# What does the Thymeleaf tag "th:for" do?

Tags: thymeleaf

Anyone know that "th:for" is in Thymeleaf? I know it's a simple question, but I can't find the answer online, even in the Thymeleaf documentation.

Comment: It is the Thymeleaf attribute equivalent of the HTML `for` attribute used by [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements. It is listed as such in the Thymeleaf documentation [section 5.2](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#setting-value-to-specific-attributes). It's no different from most other HTML attributes which have a Thymeleaf version - you can use it with a Thymeleaf expression.

Comment: @andrewjames I would suggest putting it as an answer for someone, who is looking for similar information. It's well described and may help someone else. Best regards,

Comment: OK, @SlavaIvanov - I have done so - thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the Thymeleaf attribute equivalent of the HTML for attribute used by [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements. For example:

```
<div class="preference">
    <label for="cheese">Do you like cheese?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" id="cheese">
</div>
```

It is listed in the Thymeleaf documentation [section 5.2](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#setting-value-to-specific-attributes):

> *There are quite a lot of attributes like these, each of them targeting a specific HTML5 attribute...*

It's no different from most other HTML attributes which have a Thymeleaf version - you can use it with a Thymeleaf expression. If you don't need a Thymeleaf expression, just use the plain `for` attribute instead.